# How do I insert a string between two other strings containing special characters?

Tags: linux

I am writing a script to insert the correct satellite url to `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date`

I was trying to add this command to the script:

```
sed -i 's/https//.*XMLRPC///https servername.com XMLRPC/g' /etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date
```

but I am getting :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `/` as a delimiter *and* as a lot of your regex, without using any escape. Sed can't tell the different uses apart and gets confused. You could use a `\` (backslash) in front of all the slashes in your regex and replacement pattern, but it's easier in this case to use a different delimiter. I'm a little confused by your line also, but here's my guess, using `#` as the sed pattern delimiter.:

`sed -i 's#https//.*XMLRPC#//https servername.com XMLRPC#g' /etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date`

Comment: Hi

The result from the  above command is :
serverURL=////https servername.com XMLRPC

In the script  I want to change the configuration to point to the internal satellite server
i.e 
Instead of :
serverURL=https://xmlrpc.rhn.redhat.com/XMLRPC
To be 
serverURL=https://satelliteserver.com/XMLRPC

Comment: @yossib why would `s/xmlrpc.rhn.redhat/satelliteserver/` not work?